# pathPattern wildcard with single segment

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want my app open user links that look like:

```
https://trakt.tv/users/<username>
```

but **not** sublinks of the user

```
https://trakt.tv/users/<username>/<something>
```

The pattern I'm using is `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="trakt.tv" android:pathPattern="/users/..*" />` which is not valid in my case as it opens the sublinks.

Is there a way to restrict the pattern up to /users/ but not more?

Comment: Since this uses more of a "file glob" syntax than regular expressions, I do not think that there is a way to do what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this code snippet? android:pathPattern="/users/"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).